# WSO2 API Manager redirects to 9443 in OAuth flow

Tags: api, redirect, oauth, wso2, port

We are running API Manager 1.5.0. When walking the Authorization grant, a client application makes a request to https://my.example.com/oauth2/authorize which responds with a 302 redirect to https://my.example.com:9443/authenticationendpoint (or commonauth). How do I configure API Manager to not redirect to 9443?

I have updated the config in carbon.xml with

```
<HostName>my.example.com</HostName>
```

and

```
<MgtHostName>my.example.com</MgtHostName>
```

I've also updated catalina-server.xml with proxyports (443 for 9443 and 80 for 9763). Is there another configuration needed to correct the port used in the OAuth redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Since Your running authorization server inside APIM you will be redirected to https://:9443/authenticationendpoint in authorization code grant during authorize request.
If you want to change default port follow this 
https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated the _TokenAPI and _AuthorizeAPI configs to listen on port 443, which fixes part of it, but the flow still redirects to https://:9443/authenticationendpoint. Since this is not a registered API, how do I change its port? The docs linked to mention using a system-wide offset, but that will not work here (would have to be -9000), correct?

Comment: understood the problem will get back to you soon

Comment: Can you please go to repository/conf/security application-authenticators.xml then you will find something like  <Status value="10" loginPage="https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do" /> change the port as you wish fist try by doing this even it doesn't work go to repository/conf identity.xml you will see some hard coded values in <OAuth> element change them accordingly. Please try and let me know.